# egrep for specified strings and newline

Tags: grep, regular-expression, newlines

I receive a prespecified list of strings. In a number of textfiles (example below), I want to search for strings, that do not start with one of the strings in the list. From time to time, a blank link occurs in the textfiles - my code finds them, but I don't want them either.

My script so far:

```
# The list of strings I receive
ENTRY_LIST="ACK AFF AUTH CON DIS EDITOR FUND JEL MISC PHD REF SEM TITLE VIS"

# I transform blanks to | in order to use egrep on in
TRANSFORMED_ENTRY_LIST=${ENTRY_LIST// /\|}
egrep -rvn ^"($TRANSFORMED_ENTRY_LIST):"
```

Example data is below:

```
TITLE: xxxx
AUTH: yyy
FUND: ZZZ

TITLE: BERLIN
AUTH: STUTTGART
AFF: WIEN
ACK: KIEL
CNO: HAMBURG
SEM: BRESLAU
FUND: DANZIG
```

The line `CNO: HAMBURG` is wrong, but my code also shows me line number 4.

Comment: ... add `|^$` to the end of your RE maybe?

Comment: No.4 is empty so it is included. `grep -Evrn "^($|(${ENTRY_LIST// /\|}):)"` can solve problem

Comment: I use `egrep -rvn ^"$|($TRANSFORMED_ENTRY_LIST):"` now. Costas solution finds the line twice. Who of you wants to upgrade the comment so that I can accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `|^$` to the end of your regular expression:

```
egrep -rvn "^($TRANSFORMED_ENTRY_LIST):|^\$"
```

This will reject empty lines in the input.